# What is a well-pointed bicategory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I was wondering if there was a definition for what it means for a bicategory $B$ with a terminal element $1$ (i.e. for any object $b$, the category $B(b,1)$ is equivalent to the terminal category with one object and one morphism) to be well-pointed?

Comment: I fixed the definition of terminal element. As for the question, I would imagine it to be something like $B(1,-): B \to \mathrm{Cat}$ to be conservative and locally (fully?) faithful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Do you now if there are any papers addressing this or if there is a definition for a well-pointed 2-category?

Comment: Not that I know of